# How to start in updating a published paper

Tags: extended-paper

In 2004 I published a paper on Graduate Surgical Education in a local journal. For some reason the paper has received a lot of credit and now I am approached by a Society in the USA that wants to re-publish it because according to them it is a reference paper. How do I start updating it. I never had to do this before. Thank you

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to clarify: do they want to republish the article as is, or did they ask you to make some changes and submit a new version of the article?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to "republish" the paper? Who owns the copyright?

Comment: Write the paper anew, with the new data since 2004. Compare both versions, try to keep as much as possible form the original (if that is what is being asked for).